# Object Hierarchy in QTP doesnt show Browser Object and starts with Page Hierarchy

Tags: qtp

While getting the Object Properties of Menu in an application QTP doesn't show Browser Hierarchy but instead starts from Page level.

I have navigated till below. After clicking on web element a menu appears but in Object spy that menu has its own page but no browser level hierarchy.

Browser().Page().Frame().Weblement().Click

Comment: weird. can you show the screenshot?

Comment: The Screen shot is on  http://screencast.com/t/YvTjEHRbE1

Comment: While getting the Object Properties of Menu in an application QTP doesn't show Browser Hierarchy but instead starts from Page level.

I have navigated till below. After clicking on web element a menu appears but in Object spy that menu has its own page but no browser level hierarchy.

Browser().Page().Frame().Weblement().Click

screencast.com/t/YvTjEHRbE1